# Slow internet, IP Flood?

Tags: attacks, ddos, udp

Lately, I've been getting slow internet. I checked wireshark and noticed I keep receiving in matter of seconds thousands of UDP packets that my computer does not respond to, and here's the twist: There are almost no repeating IP addresses. It's really weird.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA4t0.png
Should I be worried?
(By the way, I shut down every proccess that uses the internet including windows updater and that kind of stuff)
Running netstat on cmd shows no UDP proccess at all which is odd with all the packets...

Comment: What do the packets contain ? Also it's strange to see these packets being forwarded to your computer, usually they'll stop at the router unless the router has a good reason to forward them to your PC (if for example you first initiated a connection to these hosts yourself) or if it's in the DMZ.

Comment: Actually, I've turned on maximum firewall on my router settings, plus, disabled all DMZ and port forwarding. I'll try to specifically block the receiving ports and see if it helps.

Comment: If this is an actual attack, firewalling them won't have any effect as they're still exhausting your bandwidth. Only the ISP can help in this case by firewalling them on their side or changing your IP.

Comment: Maybe you have Port Forwarding rules from UPnP? Try to disable UPnP on your router.

Comment: It would be nice if everyone knew the whole story, including these parts from yesterday (my guess is that your computer is still compromised -- have you tried the reinstall like I suggested?): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86112/slow-internet-worried-about-spammed-packets/86114#86114